Moodle iframe activity lesson completion event
I have an iframe with a link with Moodle SCORM activity as popup display.
Is there a way to intercept the completion of the SCORM activity? For example, through a post message or another method?

The Moodle SCORM player does not have any built-in mechanism to allow you to hook custom JS onto it, or fire any postMessage events based on SCORM actions. You would have to either customize mod/scorm/datamodels/scorm_12.js, or the mod/scorm/player JS files if you wanted to be able to catch any of the SCORM events and do something additional with them.
